# how to skip from add cart and directly go review in ubercart module?

Tags: ubercart

I have developed a site in Drupal. I just want to go to review link directly from add cart.plz help to sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip yourdomain.com/cart , but linking to  **yourdomain.com/cart/checkout**.
You cannot go to yourdomain.com/cart/checkout/review though, because customer need to confirm his data.

Of course, with some heavy voodoo scripting and merging at the custom modue side, you could create unified checkout page, but that could be cumbersome task :).